# Top 20 unique traveller name based on spend with Department & Manager Name

Tags: excel-formula

I need to create a formula to pull the top 20 top spenders based on spending. I have created a pivot and am currently using Xlookup with Large to get the data. The issue is that if multiple travellers have the same spend, e.g., $100, then this formula picks the first traveller and his manager and department only and repeats the same two or three times, depending on how many times we have the same spend. I need unique travellers based on spending.

The current formula is to pull the department as mentioned below:

**Department:** `=IF($Z$5="ALL",XLOOKUP(LARGE($D$4:$D$50001,$R3),$D$4:$D$50001,$A$3:$A$50000),XLOOKUP(LARGE(IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5,$D$4:$D$50001),$R3),IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5,$D$4:$D$50001),IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5,$A$3:$A$50000)))`

**Manager Name:** `=IFERROR(IF($Z$5="ALL",XLOOKUP(LARGE($D$3:$D$50000, $R3), $D$3:$D$50000, $B$3:$B$50000),XLOOKUP(LARGE(IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5, $D$3:$D$50000), $R3), IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5,  $D$3:$D$50000), IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5, $B$3:$B$50000))),"")`

**Traveller Name:** `=IFERROR(IF($Z$5="ALL",XLOOKUP(LARGE($D$3:$D$50000, $R3), $D$3:$D$50000, $C$3:$C$50000),XLOOKUP(LARGE(IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5, $D$3:$D$50000), $R3), IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5,  $D$3:$D$50000), IF($A$3:$A$50000=$Z$5, $C$3:$C$50000))),"")`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (with those specialties described within the question) and your expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). If you use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) to insert your sample data will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: And please add which Excel version you have.

Comment: I am using Office 365.

Comment: why not use SORT with TAKE / FILTER? to sort the data based on column D and filter the sorted data on your condition, than take the first 20 rows.